# How can I add fixed (non movement) trap on animated background and platform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my 2d game my platform and background are of type scroller background how can I add a non movement trap ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fya5b.png)

Green acid is my trap

Comment: I think you should make it a child of the background so it moves accordingly to it right?

Comment: I tried this solution but it didn't work :(

Comment: Can you give more information on how this is implemented? is the background one sprite that moves or is the camera the object that's moving?

Comment: my character is fixed, my background and platform are moving with this code by the way I am using plane object for background and platform                             
    [Range(-1f,1f)]
    public float scrollSpeed = 0.5f;
    private float offset;
    private Material mat;

    
    void Start()
    {
        mat = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
        

    } 
    void Update()
    {
        offset += (Time.deltaTime * scrollSpeed) / 10f;
        mat.SetTextureOffset("_MainTex", new Vector2(offset, 0));
 
    }

Comment: Can we chat with discrod it is easier than here I think Efe Ç.#4059

Comment: Yes of course add me LamHouss#8877